# Generic Postgres 9.5 trigger to convert an UPDATE into modified INSERT

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

Is it possible to create a generic (not table-specific) trigger in Postgres 9.5 that would perform on `instead of update` that converts the update into an insert?

Basically what I want to do is (pseudocode):

`sql
instead of UPDATE on TG_TABLE_NAME INSERT on TG_TABLE_NAME`

I know I can create a very table-specific trigger that maps each value into an insert statement. What I'm trying to do is get away from creating this trigger on every single table.

Comment: Is there something preventing you from changing the initial update into an insert before you execute the query?

Comment: It's more a safety thing. People should not update to this table, it's an audit table. But if they did... well, you could just change it into an insert and it would be fine...

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit of an oddball idea (nothing personal), but how about this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION not_update_but_insert() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TG_TABLE_NAME  -- Do an INSERT...
    SELECT NEW.*;            -- ... using the values from the row to be updated
  RETURN NULL;               -- Fail the UPDATE
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Obviously this would not work for any table that has a `PRIMARY KEY` or other `UNIQUE` constraints. You do have to `CREATE TRIGGER x BEFORE UPDATE` for every table this would apply to, so analyze your table structure before creating the trigger.

There is obviously a work-around - at least for the PKs based on a `sequence` - by examining the `information_schema` for "safe" columns in `TG_TABLE_NAME` and then assembling their names into strings to splice into the `INSERT` statement (column list of main statement and select list). Just leave the columns with sequences or appropriate default values out. This, however, does not address `UNIQUE` constraints that have no obvious replacement (like a user name or an email address).

Comment: This looks pretty good... but, PKs are involved. I'll give it a try and see what develops...